# fbthrift - build failed with getdps.py on Mac OS 13.4 for

Tags: c++, cmake, thrift

I used cmake provided in the fbthrift () to build the fbthrift project

But get the following error:

```
[build] FAILED: thrift/annotation/CMakeFiles/thriftannotation.dir/gen-cpp2/cpp_data.cpp.o 
[build] /usr/bin/clang++ -DBOOST_ATOMIC_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_ATOMIC_NO_LIB -DBOOST_CONTEXT_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_CONTEXT_NO_LIB -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_NO_LIB -DBOOST_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_NO_LIB -DBOOST_REGEX_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_REGEX_NO_LIB -DBOOST_SYSTEM_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_LIB -DBOOST_THREAD_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_THREAD_NO_LIB -DFMT_SHARED -DGFLAGS_IS_A_DLL=0 -DTHRIFT_HAVE_LIBSNAPPY=0 -I/Users/kaiqu/Developer/fbthrift/. -I/Users/kaiqu/Developer/fbthrift/build -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include -isystem /opt/homebrew/include -isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include -isystem /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -g -std=c++17 -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk -MD -MT thrift/annotation/CMakeFiles/thriftannotation.dir/gen-cpp2/cpp_data.cpp.o -MF thrift/annotation/CMakeFiles/thriftannotation.dir/gen-cpp2/cpp_data.cpp.o.d -o thrift/annotation/CMakeFiles/thriftannotation.dir/gen-cpp2/cpp_data.cpp.o -c /Users/kaiqu/Developer/fbthrift/build/thrift/annotation/gen-cpp2/cpp_data.cpp
[build] In file included from /Users/kaiqu/Developer/fbthrift/build/thrift/annotation/gen-cpp2/cpp_data.cpp:8:
[build] In file included from /Users/kaiqu/Developer/fbthrift/build/thrift/annotation/gen-cpp2/cpp_data.h:9:
[build] In file included from /Users/kaiqu/Developer/fbthrift/./thrift/lib/cpp2/gen/module_data_h.h:22:
[build] In file included from /Users/kaiqu/Developer/fbthrift/./thrift/lib/cpp/Thrift.h:20:
[build] In file included from /opt/homebrew/include/folly/Range.h:62:
[build] /opt/homebrew/include/fmt/format.h:2797:38: error: expected unqualified-id
[build] template <typename T> constexpr bool isnan(T value) {
[build]                                      ^
[build] /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/math.h:165:7: note: expanded from macro 'isnan'
[build]     ( sizeof(x) == sizeof(float)  ? __inline_isnanf((float)(x))          \
[build]       ^
[build] In file included from /Users/kaiqu/Developer/fbthrift/build/thrift/annotation/gen-cpp2/cpp_data.cpp:8:
[build] In file included from /Users/kaiqu/Developer/fbthrift/build/thrift/annotation/gen-cpp2/cpp_data.h:9:
[build] In file included from /Users/kaiqu/Developer/fbthrift/./thrift/lib/cpp2/gen/module_data_h.h:22:
[build] In file included from /Users/kaiqu/Developer/fbthrift/./thrift/lib/cpp/Thrift.h:20:
[build] In file included from /opt/homebrew/include/folly/Range.h:62:
[build] /opt/homebrew/include/fmt/format.h:2797:38: error: expected ')'
[build] /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/math.h:165:7: note: expanded from macro 'isnan'
[build]     ( sizeof(x) == sizeof(float)  ? __inline_isnanf((float)(x))          \
[build]       ^
[build] /opt/homebrew/include/fmt/format.h:2797:38: note: to match this '('
[build] /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/math.h:165:5: note: expanded from macro 'isnan'
[build]     ( sizeof(x) == sizeof(float)  ? __inline_isnanf((float)(x))          \
[build]     ^
[build] In file included from /Users/kaiqu/Developer/fbthrift/build/thrift/annotation/gen-cpp2/cpp_data.cpp:8:
[build] In file included from /Users/kaiqu/Developer/fbthrift/build/thrift/annotation/gen-cpp2/cpp_data.h:9:
[build] In file included from /Users/kaiqu/Developer/fbthrift/./thrift/lib/cpp2/gen/module_data_h.h:22:
[build] In file included from /Users/kaiqu/Developer/fbthrift/./thrift/lib/cpp/Thrift.h:20:
[build] In file included from /opt/homebrew/include/folly/Range.h:62:
[build] /opt/homebrew/include/fmt/format.h:2805:48: error: expected unqualified-id
[build] struct has_isfinite<T, enable_if_t<sizeof(std::isfinite(T())) != 0>>
[build]                                                ^
[build] /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/math.h:155:5: note: expanded from macro 'isfinite'
[build]     ( sizeof(x) == sizeof(float)  ? __inline_isfinitef((float)(x))       \
[build]     ^
[build] In file included from /Users/kaiqu/Developer/fbthrift/build/thrift/annotation/gen-cpp2/cpp_data.cpp:8:
[build] In file included from /Users/kaiqu/Developer/fbthrift/build/thrift/annotation/gen-cpp2/cpp_data.h:9:
[build] In file included from /Users/kaiqu/Developer/fbthrift/./thrift/lib/cpp2/gen/module_data_h.h:22:
[build] In file included from /Users/kaiqu/Developer/fbthrift/./thrift/lib/cpp/Thrift.h:20:
[build] In file included from /opt/homebrew/include/folly/Range.h:62:
[build] /opt/homebrew/include/fmt/format.h:2805:8: error: explicit specialization of undeclared template struct 'has_isfinite'
[build] struct has_isfinite<T, enable_if_t<sizeof(std::isfinite(T())) != 0>>
[build]        ^           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] /opt/homebrew/include/fmt/format.h:2810:22: error: expected unqualified-id
[build] FMT_CONSTEXPR20 bool isfinite(T value) {
[build]                      ^
[build] /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/math.h:155:7: note: expanded from macro 'isfinite'
[build]     ( sizeof(x) == sizeof(float)  ? __inline_isfinitef((float)(x))       \
[build]       ^
[build] In file included from /Users/kaiqu/Developer/fbthrift/build/thrift/annotation/gen-cpp2/cpp_data.cpp:8:
[build] In file included from /Users/kaiqu/Developer/fbthrift/build/thrift/annotation/gen-cpp2/cpp_data.h:9:
[build] In file included from /Users/kaiqu/Developer/fbthrift/./thrift/lib/cpp2/gen/module_data_h.h:22:
[build] In file included from /Users/kaiqu/Developer/fbthrift/./thrift/lib/cpp/Thrift.h:20:
[build] In file included from /opt/homebrew/include/folly/Range.h:62:
[build] /opt/homebrew/include/fmt/format.h:2810:22: error: expected ')'
[build] /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/math.h:155:7: note: expanded from macro 'isfinite'
[build]     ( sizeof(x) == sizeof(float)  ? __inline_isfinitef((float)(x))       \
[build]       ^
[build] /opt/homebrew/include/fmt/format.h:2810:22: note: to match this '('
[build] /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/math.h:155:5: note: expanded from macro 'isfinite'
[build]     ( sizeof(x) == sizeof(float)  ? __inline_isfinitef((float)(x))       \
[build]     ^
[build] In file included from /Users/kaiqu/Developer/fbthrift/build/thrift/annotation/gen-cpp2/cpp_data.cpp:8:
[build] In file included from /Users/kaiqu/Developer/fbthrift/build/thrift/annotation/gen-cpp2/cpp_data.h:9:
[build] In file included from /Users/kaiqu/Developer/fbthrift/./thrift/lib/cpp2/gen/module_data_h.h:22:
[build] In file included from /Users/kaiqu/Developer/fbthrift/./thrift/lib/cpp/Thrift.h:20:
[build] In file included from /opt/homebrew/include/folly/Range.h:62:
[build] /opt/homebrew/include/fmt/format.h:2842:22: error: unknown type name 'round_direction'
[build] FMT_CONSTEXPR inline round_direction get_round_direction(uint64_t divisor,
[build]                      ^
[build] /opt/homebrew/include/fmt/format.h:2850:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'round_direction'
[build]     return round_direction::down;
[build]            ^
[build] /opt/homebrew/include/fmt/format.h:2854:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'round_direction'
[build]     return round_direction::up;
[build]            ^
[build] /opt/homebrew/include/fmt/format.h:2856:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'round_direction'
[build]   return round_direction::unknown;
[build]          ^
[build] /opt/homebrew/include/fmt/format.h:2890:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'round_direction'
[build]     if (dir != round_direction::up)
[build]                ^
[build] /opt/homebrew/include/fmt/format.h:2891:21: error: use of undeclared identifier 'round_direction'
[build]       return dir == round_direction::down ? digits::done : digits::error;
[build]                     ^
[build] /opt/homebrew/include/fmt/format.h:2943:18: error: use of undeclared identifier 'round_direction'
[build]       if (dir == round_direction::unknown) return digits::error;
[build]                  ^
[build] /opt/homebrew/include/fmt/format.h:2944:44: error: use of undeclared identifier 'round_direction'
[build]       handler.buf[handler.size++] = dir == round_direction::up ? '1' : '0';
[build]                                            ^
[build] /opt/homebrew/include/fmt/format.h:3824:15: error: expected unqualified-id
[build]   if (detail::signbit(value)) {  // value < 0 is false for NaN so use signbit.
[build]               ^
[build] /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/math.h:170:5: note: expanded from macro 'signbit'
[build]     ( sizeof(x) == sizeof(float)  ? __inline_signbitf((float)(x))        \
[build]     ^
```

...

I checked line 2797 of `format.h`, as the error log suggested, which is the first line in the code snippet below, but it seems that the definition of the function is defined correctly:

```
template <typename T> constexpr bool isnan(T value) {
  return !(value >= value);  // std::isnan doesn't support __float128.
}
```

I tried setting the CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD to a newer value but it did not work...Could someone give me some pointers about where the problem is?

Comment: `note: expanded from macro 'isnan'` - The header `/opt/homebrew/include/fmt/format.h` attempts to define a template **function** `isnan`, but `isnan` is already defined as a **macro** in the header `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/math.h`. I am not expert in MacOS, but probably mixing MacOSX13.sdk and homebrew is not a good idea.